# Magento category attribute can't access

Tags: php, sql, magento, magento-1.9, entity-attribute-value

I used a code to add select box on category modify page, which works correctly and my selected values are saves when i save category, code is here

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'leasing',  array(
'group'         => 'General Information',
'type'     => 'int',
'label'    => 'Lease',
'input'    => 'select',
'source'   => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'required' => false,
'default'  => 1,
'user_defined'  => 1,
'default'  => 0
));
```

[image]

But when i try to get the saved value of above select box on fronted product detail page, and it's not working and shows "NULL" when i use var_dump. i already tried by index but no luck.

here is the code i used.

```
$catid = Mage::registry('current_category') ? Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : null;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid);
echo $category ->getLeasing();
echo $category ->getData('leasing');
```

Anyone know how to fix this, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The category flat index needs to be refreshed when you add a custom attribute because the flat category flag is usually set to yes by default.

System > Index Management > Reindex Data